# Difference of datetime type in mysql 5.5.46 and 5.6.28

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Have table in `mysql 5.5.46` and same table in `5.6.28`. I backup database on `mysql 5.5.46` and then restore it on `5.6.28`. So table have same structure and same data on both servers.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Path` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `Link` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `Company` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `Width` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Height` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `View_Count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Have query like this :

```
insert into test(path,link,company,width,height,view_count)
values('test','test','test',10,10,10)
```

On `mysql 5.5.46` this query execute successfully and create_date value is `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`

On `mysql 5.6.28` have an error `Field 'Create_Date' doesn't have a default value` and it's logically because create_date is not null so it does not have any default value. But how it works on `5.5.46` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information you gave us, it appears that you were running MySQL `5.5.46` in non strict mode, but running MySQL `5.6.28` in strict mode.  From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html):

> TIMESTAMP columns declared as NOT NULL and without an explicit DEFAULT clause are treated as having no default value. For inserted rows that specify no explicit value for such a column, the result depends on the SQL mode. If strict SQL mode is enabled, an error occurs. If strict SQL mode is not enabled, the column is assigned the implicit default of '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and a warning occurs. **This is similar to how MySQL treats other temporal types such as DATETIME.**

Your `create_date` column is of type `DATETIME`, and it appears that you were trying to do the `INSERT` in the `5.6.28` database in strict mode, and hence getting an error.

Comment: thank you for answer. `SET @@global.sql_mode= '';` helped me